# Spring Security 3.0 and Active Directory LDAP: DOMAIN\user login

Tags: spring, active-directory, ldap, spring-security, spring-ldap

I would like to have users authenticate against an ActiveDirectory LDAP server using the DOMAIN\user.name syntax. I think that should be possible with SpringSec 3.0 since the docs [mention an alternative syntax](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html#ldap-ldap-authenticators-active-directory) which I guess refers to the DOM\user syntax instead of a bind DN, but the docs don't elaborate further.

Is there some way to configure Spring Sec 3 LDAP to use "the MS way" or do I have to write my own Authenticator implementation (against e.g. the java.naming.directory package, which I've tested to be able to use the MS syntax as its SECURITY_PRINCIPAL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Spring Security 3.1, it has built-in support for binding against AD.

Comment: Good hint. I wrote a whole SSO service that does AD auth in the meantime, so it's a moot point. :-b ...but for the original question it's definitely the way to go!

Comment: Bernd, I'd rather do Kerberos auth and then lookup additional data in AD. You could spare your users the login procedure.